# IIS Configuration LifeCycle, Security for ASP.net Webservies

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-services, iis, axapta

I have created a web service using ASP .Net. My web service contains a web config file, which stores security information of our Microsoft Dynamics Axapta AOS server, username and password for Axapta authentication.

My web service calls a Dynamics Axapta web service and exchanges some data. I have deployed my ASP .Net web service to IIS 7.0 which is located in DMZ zone. Now i have to give web service address to a payment service. This payment service should only know the web service address and the methods of this web service. This is my first time, i am developing such a service stored in IIS:

My question is:

How i need to configure IIS? (Authentication)
Which security tips i need to follow?
What should i do, to make my web config file to be secure?
How i need to allow this payment service to my local server?

Any suggestions and explanation will be huge help to me, because i am newbie to this topic.

Thanks a lot, sincerely, Ilkin.

Comment: Maybe this is more a Serverfault question?

Comment: Maybe, Yes. But i really waiting for an answer and it is urgent.

Answer (score 0):

Your *IIS Application Pool* should run as *custom account* identity (like `domain\svc-ax-payment-user`). Then add this Active Directory user to AX users and grant / add it to role with access to required roles. In this scenario password is saved securely in IIS.

---

Another option is to encrypt password with machine key (eg. your IIS server is not trusted in AX domain).

```
aspnet_regiis.exe -pef "appSettings" C:\web_app_dir
```

Run this command as administrator.

Check [How To: Encrypt Configuration Sections](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff647398.aspx) for more information.

You can also create your [own *Machine Key*](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms998288.aspx) for your application. In this case your `web.config` is portable and not bound to one specific server.

Comment: There is also good sample of custom coded encryption: http://weblogs.asp.net/jongalloway/encrypting-passwords-in-a-net-app-config-file

Comment: Hello,Thanks for your reply. I also made a research and came to this solution, This is what i did also. I have added a new section to my web config file that stores Active directory Name, Domain and Password, also a link to Axapta web service, than i encrypted it using machine key, and i enabled windows authentication on IIS. Is this all i should do for entire security ? or any other option i can do?